# Nginx reverse proxy configuration to handle absolute paths

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running a web application on `http://localhost:9000`
that I would like to reverse proxy to `http://localhost/myapplication`.

The problem is that the application is using absolute paths `<a href="/some-directory/some-file.html">link</a>` which is translated to `http://localhost/some-directory/some-file.html` with my current configuration.

How do I configure nginx to handle these paths so that they point to `http://localhost/myapplication/some-directory/some-file.html` instead?

Right now the proxy pass configuration looks like this:

```
    location /myapplication/ {
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:9000/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: There is no right way to do it in nginx. Fix application to use relative path or add prefix to absolute path (if it's possible).

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Is it possible to make the web application work with and without the proxy in case of adding the prefix to the absolute path? If I am correct there are cases when it is not possible to add relative paths. For example if the server returns HTML with a button that has `onclick` event whish sends GET request to some path relative to the `/` of the website. After adding the relative path and proxy rule to remove it from the path the webpage can't work anymore without the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Similar question to https://serverfault.com/questions/714322/nginx-proxy-pass-and-absolute-paths. So here is my answer from over there (slightly adapted for your example):

The only way I found to make this work is to use the [HttpSubModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) and adding `sub_filter` directives. So given your example it could look like this:

```
sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/myapplication/';
```

Obviously the more specific your matching is the more variants you'll have to add. If you go less specific, like just match `"/` or `'/` then you need less rules but run into the danger of substituting the wrong thing.

You probably also need to add:

```
sub_filter_types *;
```

So it doesn't just match `text/html` (which is the default) but also javascript and css files. Obviously `*` is the lazy approach which might break things and using specific mimetypes should be preferred.

Ultimately the correct way is to fix the web application. Most web frameworks support something like a base url/root url/url prefix (there doesn't seem to be standard name for this) which you can set to avoid exactly this problem.